# Naudio Open Source audio - How do I make my sample louder?

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

dll in c# to record a 5 second sample.
It's not very loud at all when I listen to the recording so I think something is incorrect about when I record the samples.

The function does currently record for 5 seconds.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
//AUDIO RECORDING AND SAVING
        private void startRecording(String location, float seconds)
        {
            silence = true;
            //deviceNumber = NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.GetCapabilities(0);
            deviceNumber = 0;

            //setup audio stream in
            sourceStream = new NAudio.Wave.WaveIn();
            sourceStream.DeviceNumber = deviceNumber;
            sourceStream.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(44100, NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.GetCapabilities(deviceNumber).Channels);
            //NAudio.Wave.WaveInProvider waveIn = new NAudio.Wave.WaveInProvider(sourceStream);

            //save .wav file2
            String wavLocation = appLocation + location + now.DayOfYear + @"_" + now.Year + @"_" + now.Hour + @"-" + now.Minute + @"-" + now.Second + @".wav";
            sourceStream.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs>(sourceStream_DataAvailable);
            waveWriter = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileWriter(wavLocation, sourceStream.WaveFormat);

            //record
            sourceStream.StartRecording();

            //set recording timer, end in 5s
            myTimer.Interval = ((int)(seconds * 1000)) + 1000;
            //when the timer ticks (at each interval), the function "stopRecording" is called.
            //in stop recording, there is asynchronous code.
            myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(stopRecording);
            myTimer.Start();
        }
```

Comment: if you are hearing what you were recording when you play back the WAV file, then there is no issue with your code. Instead the microphone record level is probably too low. Open the windows audio devices panel and have a look.

Comment: Mark,

I've read lots of your articles.  You created Naudio correct?

Comment: Ok, but my problem is that Naudio or my recordings specifically sound so much softer than normal.  I just tested mic through loopback of my speakers (plugged in headphones) and the levels sound fine.  I'm also using some sort of speech recognition and it picks up my voice really well.  It just seems so much softer when I record and then play back through the .wav file I created with Naudio and is played with VLC media player.   Any advice?

Comment: well assuming you pass the recorded bytes directly to a WaveFileWriter, then you are getting audio at whatever level the mic is set to. You can amplify the samples, but when recording, the right thing to do is to record at a good level.

Comment: I took your advice, and it definitely does help.  Thanks!